# Which IMG file from ISO to patch with Magisk to use on Android-x86 9 Pie?

Tags: rooting, android-x86, magisk

Setup:

- Oracle VirtualBox VM with installed Android-x86 9 (Pie)

  - Rooted out of the box (with SuperSU, guessing from the root access popup, but there's no manager app)
  - `.vmdk` VM drive
- `android-x86_64-9.0-r1.iso`

  - Files on it:
  - [image: files on android-x86_64-9.0-r1.iso in Explorer]

Which one of the `.img` files on this ISO should I use for Magisk Manager [boot image patching](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#boot-image-patching) installation?

Comment: I would like to know!